# Android game location on screen size

Tags: android, screen

Right now my game is using direct x and y values. I realized that my the S3 was scaling my images double size along with some other size inconsistencies between devices. I read around and learned a bit about android dpi and scaling and stuff.
I'm wondering whats the correct way to do locations and stuff so that it takes into account different screen sizes.

I'm thinking it can be done by setting a target dimension and then scaling all positional values according to the ratio of the target dimension to the actual screen size.

I also read somewhere that you can draw onto a buffer and display that buffer stretched to the screensize, however for this method would android's auto resizing affect the drawn bitmaps?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to use aspect ratio, android auto resizing to your benefit. Every android screen has its own aspect ratio, your game should use the aspect ratio and fill blackborder where ever there is a need to fill space on the screen. So use appropriate root layout fitting attributes.

Android resizes drawables automatically that dont fit. So if you keep only 1 set of drawables, the resizing work for Android increases and it uses Bitmap's internally to do the resize. More the bitmaps more the memory utilization, more the cleanup, more the GC and slower your game. So the best practice here is to create different dpi different image sets to use.

To start with I suggest that you purchase 3 phones, samsung y (small screen), samsung s2 (good screen) and a tab 7 or 10 inch. Copy your original drawables to all the folders, just to get a feel of the game and to eliminate all memory issues. Once your game works nicely, smoothly without any memory issues on all the phone sizes, just walk into a graphic designers office and show him how bad your game looks on some phones. He will create graphics that will work for that dpi.

Its a game of intelligent drawable resolution, sizing and A WHOLE LOAD OF TESTING :).

Hope this has helped.

Edit : Read my answer in [memory issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996210/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-2-error-inflating-class-u/12996233#12996233)

Comment: Thanks, but how do I deal with the positional values of game objects.

Comment: Move by %'s instead of absolute values. And relative positioning.