# How to resolve a stack trace error

Tags: android, xml

I have an Android app which has a minimum SDK at 2.1 and I am getting the following stack trace in the developer console:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.versions.MyPhone}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2705)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2721)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:132)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2071)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4669)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:876)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:634)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:203)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1656)
at com.versions.MyPhone.onCreate(MyPhone.java:49)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2669)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:115)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:468)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:435)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:340)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:488)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:462)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:323)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1885)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1834)
at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:285)
```

The error doesn't happen in the newer devices with an updated Os.

Please help me resolve the issue or point me in the right direction.

Comment: What is the image extension(png.jpg) you are trying to resize?

Comment: check it, possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996210/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-2-error-inflating-class-u

Answer (score 1):

Based on the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget` message in the stack trace, it appears that one of the images in the view being opened in your onCreate() is too large.

Here's a [page](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) with some guidance. The main idea is to load a scaled down version of the image. I've found it best to also scale down (resolution, color-depth, etc.) the actual image file to maximize loading speed.