# what is the suitable size for a background image to avoid crashes?

Tags: java, android

I am working on my android application and i have this Error

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

with this line in java Activity:

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_complaint);
```

I think the back Ground is the responsible for that. So 
what is the suitable size and extension of image for android to avoid crushing or any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12996233/7339411

you have to put your image in the drawable folder and then you have to get it in the xml layout in this way:

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/insertphotohere"
```