# Having error in some devices "android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>"

Tags: java, android, xml

I am having an `Issue: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>` On some devices.

It happens while inflating in Adapter in `RecyclerView` (As found from the log).

The crash happens in the following devices.

- [vivo v5](https://www.gsmarena.com/vivo_v5-8430.php)
- [K3 2017](https://www.gsmarena.com/lg_k3_(2017)-8488.php)
- [Moto G4 Play](https://www.gsmarena.com/motorola_moto_g4_play-8104.php)
- Oppo f4

**EDIT -** All crashing devices have android 6

The crash **does not** happens in the following devices.

- [OnePlus 5t](https://www.gsmarena.com/oneplus_5t-8912.php)
- [Galaxy S9](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s9-8966.php)
- [Xperia XZ1 Compact](https://www.gsmarena.com/sony_xperia_xz1_compact-8610.php)

`AdapterAnimationPicker.java`

```
@Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        context = parent.getContext();

        // error happening below line
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_animation_picker,parent,false);
        mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(context);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }
```

`card_animation_picker.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_card_primary">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/card_anim_picker_framelayout"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_card_primary"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,16:9"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
                <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
                    android:id="@+id/card_anim_picker_animation_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            </FrameLayout>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.github.florent37.expansionpanel.ExpansionLayout
        app:expansion_expanded="false"
        android:id="@+id/card_anim_picker_expansionLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="4dp">
            <Button
                app:cornerRadius="9999dp"
                app:rippleColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:id="@+id/card_anim_picker_edit_btn"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryLessLight"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="edit"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.github.florent37.expansionpanel.ExpansionLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the log files

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.w3saver.typography, PID: 16223
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at com.w3saver.typography.Adapters.AdapterAnimationPicker.onCreateViewHolder(AdapterAnimationPicker.java:52)
    at com.w3saver.typography.Adapters.AdapterAnimationPicker.onCreateViewHolder(AdapterAnimationPicker.java:27)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6794)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5975)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LayoutState.next(LayoutState.java:100)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.fill(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:1609)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:683)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:605)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3336)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5955)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5955)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5955)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5955)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5955)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5955)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2112)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1228)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1464)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1119)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6060)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Loo
```

Thnings that i have already tried

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/12996233/7405050

I have no idea what is wrong with my code i am digging this issue from last 2 days. If someone help fegureit out then that would be so helpful.

Comment: android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_card_primary"
remove the above line and test once is it working? If yes please mention in comment will give you solution

Comment: okay will get back to you after testing, Thanks

Comment: @AbhinavGupta I have removed 
 this line `android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_card_primary"` and my code is running fine now thanks. but what is the solution here?

Comment: use png file in drawable not in drwable-24 but one thing paste in xxhdpi then test in all devices. Definitely, it will work in all devices. If it is not an image only shape thing please share that xml in your question @KartikGarasia

Comment: hey that solved my problem.. please answer it on answer section I will accept it so other people can find the solution more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

use png file in drawable not in drwable-24 but one thing paste in xxhdpi then test in all devices. Definitely, it will work in all devices. If it is not an image only shape thing please share that xml in your question.

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

**android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_card_primary"**

Probably this is the problem. If this is an SVG file and you are using **Offset** property in this file it will crash in marshmallow. So better make a sperate file for marshmallow devices and use png file.

Refer https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html

Comment: No i am just using radius and shape property and it is xml file

Comment: Add that as well. Whatever you are using.